# Creating a table from a Snowpark DataFrame by specifying column names and their respective data types

Tags: python, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to do the following, and if so, how?

1. Create a table, with the table name and column names and types specified dynamically.
2. Pass in column names and types with parameters

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems the answer is **Yes**

I found 2 options:

- you can write a SQL query in python and pass in names/types dynamically. The SQL query is just a string which you can manipulate, i.e.

```
# Define the dynamic column names and data types
column_info = [
    ("MYCOL_123", "VARCHAR"),
    ("MYCOL_456", "INT"),
    ("MYCOL_789", "DOUBLE"),
]

# Build the dynamic column definitions
column_definitions = ", ".join([f"{name} {data_type}" for name, data_type in column_info])

# Build the dynamic SQL query
sql_query = f"""
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MY_TABLE({column_definitions})
"""

# Execute the dynamic SQL query
session.sql(sql_query).collect()
```

- if your starting point is a pandas dataframe you can use [write_pandas](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Session.write_pandas) to create the table